# Black layer on top of title bar (minimize/maximize/close) in Win7

Tags: c#, windows-7, infragistics, aero, titlebar

We have a .NET 2.0 application using WinForms and Infragistics 7.2. The title bar for our application has what appears to a black bar layered on it which is covering the minimize, maximize and close buttons.  The buttons are still there (as evidenced by the hover colouring and tooltips in the screen shot) and still work when you click in the correct location, but the buttons themselves are not visible.

[image: Black Title Bar]

This is only happening on a few Win7 machines, and may be theme related?  We have other applications using the same framework/technology running on the same machine, but they don't have this problem.  At one point a PC had this problem in a debug build running through VS2010, but an installed release (same source code) didn't. We've tried exporting themes from one PC to the other but the problem doesn't appear to be exported with it.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I suggest you contact the UI framework vendor and make use of their support service. It will be a lot easier for them to work it out than anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem and I solved it by changing the FormBorderStyle:

```
FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
```

Hope this helps.